# How to make a SPA SEO crawlable?

Tags: ajax, seo, phantomjs, single-page-application, durandal

I've been working on how to make a SPA crawlable by google based on google's [instructions](https://developers.google.com/webmasters/ajax-crawling/?hl=iw&csw=1). Even though there are quite a few general explanations I couldn't find anywhere a more thorough step-by-step tutorial with actual examples.  After having finished this I would like to share my solution so that others may also make use of it and possibly improve it further. 
 
I am using `MVC` with `Webapi` controllers, and [Phantomjs](http://phantomjs.org/) on the server side, and [Durandal](http://durandaljs.com/) on the client side with `push-state` enabled; I also use [Breezejs](http://www.breezejs.com/) for client-server data interaction, all of which I strongly recommend, but I'll try to give a general enough explanation that will also help people using other platforms.

Comment: concerning the "off topic" - a web app programmer has to find a way how to make his/her app crawlable for SEO, this is a basic requirement on the web.  Doing this is not about programming per se, but it is relevant to the subject of "practical, answerable problems that are unique to the programming profession" as described in http://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic.  It is a problem for many programmers with no clear solutions on the entire web.  I was hoping to help others and invested hours in just describing it here, getting negative points certainly doesn't motivate me to help again.

Comment: If the emphasis is on the programming and not snake oil/secret sauce SEO voodoo/spam then it can be perfectly topical. We also like self answers where they have the potential to be useful to future readers long term. This question & answer pair seems to pass both those tests. (Some of the background details could flesh out the question better rather than being introduced in the answer but that's fairly minor)

Comment: +1 to mitigate down votes. Regardless if q/a would be better suited as blog post, the question is relevant to Durandal and the answer is well researched.

Comment: I agree that SEO is an important part nowadays of the developers everydays life and should definitely be considered as a topic in stackoverflow!

Comment: Other than implementing the whole process yourself, you can try SnapSearch https://snapsearch.io which basically addresses this problem as a service.

Answer (score 120):

Before starting, please make sure you understand what google [requires](https://developers.google.com/webmasters/ajax-crawling/?hl=iw&csw=1), particularly the use of *pretty* and *ugly* URLs.  Now lets see the implementation:

#### Client Side

On the client side you only have a single html page which interacts with the server dynamically via AJAX calls.  that's what SPA is about. All the `a` tags in the client side are created dynamically in my application, we'll later see how to make these links visible to google's bot in the server.  Each such `a` tag needs to be able to have a `pretty URL` in the `href` tag so that google's bot will crawl it.  You don't want the `href` part to be used when the client clicks on it (even though you do want the server to be able to parse it, we'll see that later), because we may not want a new page to load, only to make an AJAX call getting some data to be displayed in part of the page and change the URL via javascript (e.g. using HTML5 `pushstate` or with `Durandaljs`). So, we have both an `href` attribute for google as well as on `onclick` which does the job when the user clicks on the link.  Now, since I use `push-state` I don't want any `#` on the URL, so a typical `a` tag may look like this: 
`<a href="http://www.xyz.com/#!/category/subCategory/product111" onClick="loadProduct('category','subCategory','product111')>see product111...</a>`
'category' and 'subCategory' would probably be other phrases, such as 'communication' and 'phones' or 'computers' and 'laptops' for an electrical appliances store.  Obviously there would be many different categories and sub categories. As you can see, the link is directly to the category, sub category and the product, not as extra-parameters to a specific 'store' page such as `http://www.xyz.com/store/category/subCategory/product111`.  This is because I prefer shorter and simpler links.  It implies that I there will not be a category with the same name as one of my 'pages', i.e. 'about'. 
I will not go into how to load the data via AJAX (the `onclick` part), search it on google, there are many good explanations.  The only important thing here that I do want to mention is that when the user clicks on this link, I want the URL in the browser to look like this:
`http://www.xyz.com/category/subCategory/product111`.  And this is URL is not sent to the server !  remember, this is a SPA where all the interaction between the client and the server is done via AJAX, no links at all!  all 'pages' are implemented on the client side, and the different URL does not make a call to the server (the server does need to know how to handle these URLs in case they are used as external links from another site to your site, we'll see that later on the server side part).  Now, this is handled wonderfully by Durandal.  I strongly recommend it, but you can also skip this part if you prefer other technologies.  If you do choose it, and you're also using MS Visual Studio Express 2012 for Web like me, you can install the [Durandal Starter Kit](https://www.nuget.org/packages/Durandal.StarterKit), and there, in `shell.js`, use something like this:

```
define(['plugins/router', 'durandal/app'], function (router, app) {
    return {
        router: router,
        activate: function () {
            router.map([
                { route: '', title: 'Store', moduleId: 'viewmodels/store', nav: true },
                { route: 'about', moduleId: 'viewmodels/about', nav: true }
            ])
                .buildNavigationModel()
                .mapUnknownRoutes(function (instruction) {
                    instruction.config.moduleId = 'viewmodels/store';
                    instruction.fragment = instruction.fragment.replace("!/", ""); // for pretty-URLs, '#' already removed because of push-state, only ! remains
                    return instruction;
                });
            return router.activate({ pushState: true });
        }
    };
});
```

There are a few important things to notice here:

1. The first route (with `route:''`) is for the URL which has no extra data in it, i.e. `http://www.xyz.com`.  In this page you load general data using AJAX.  There may actually be no `a` tags at all in this page.  You will want to add the following tag so that google's bot will know what to do with it: 
   `<meta name="fragment" content="!">`.  This tag will make google's bot transform the URL to `www.xyz.com?_escaped_fragment_=` which we'll see later.
2. The 'about' route is just an example to a link to other 'pages' you may want on your web application.
3. Now, the tricky part is that there is no 'category' route, and there may be many different categories - none of which have a predefined route.  This is where `mapUnknownRoutes` comes in.  It maps these unknown routes to the 'store' route and also removes any '!' from the URL in case it's a `pretty URL` generated by google's seach engine.  The 'store' route takes the info in the 'fragment' property and makes the AJAX call to get the data, display it, and change the URL locally.  In my application, I don't load a different page for every such call; I only change the part of the page where this data is relevant and also change the URL locally.
4. Notice the `pushState:true` which instructs Durandal to use push state URLs.

This is all we need in the client side.  It can be implemented also with hashed URLs (in Durandal you simple remove the `pushState:true` for that).  The more complex part (at least for me...) was the server part:

#### Server Side

I'm using `MVC 4.5` on the server side with `WebAPI` controllers.  The server actually needs to handle 3 types of URLs: the ones generated by google - both `pretty` and `ugly` and also a 'simple' URL with the same format as the one that appears in the client's browser.  Lets look on how to do this:

Pretty URLs and 'simple' ones are first interpreted by the server as if trying to reference a non-existent controller.  The server sees something like `http://www.xyz.com/category/subCategory/product111` and looks for a controller named 'category'.  So in `web.config` I add the following line to redirect these to a specific error handling controller:

```
<customErrors mode="On" defaultRedirect="Error">
    <error statusCode="404" redirect="Error" />
</customErrors><br/>
```

Now, this transforms the URL to something like: `http://www.xyz.com/Error?aspxerrorpath=/category/subCategory/product111`.  I want the URL to be sent to the client that will load the data via AJAX, so the trick here is to call the default 'index' controller as if not referencing any controller; I do that by *adding* a hash to the URL before all the 'category' and 'subCategory' parameters; the hashed URL does not require any special controller except the default 'index' controller and the data is sent to the client which then removes the hash and uses the info after the hash to load the data via AJAX.  Here is the error handler controller code:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Net;
using System.Net.Http;
using System.Web.Http;

using System.Web.Routing;

namespace eShop.Controllers
{
    public class ErrorController : ApiController
    {
        [HttpGet, HttpPost, HttpPut, HttpDelete, HttpHead, HttpOptions, AcceptVerbs("PATCH"), AllowAnonymous]
        public HttpResponseMessage Handle404()
        {
            string [] parts = Request.RequestUri.OriginalString.Split(new[] { '?' }, StringSplitOptions.RemoveEmptyEntries);
            string parameters = parts[ 1 ].Replace("aspxerrorpath=","");
            var response = Request.CreateResponse(HttpStatusCode.Redirect);
            response.Headers.Location = new Uri(parts[0].Replace("Error","") + string.Format("#{0}", parameters));
            return response;
        }
    }
}
```

But what about the *Ugly URLs*?  These are created by google's bot and should return plain HTML that contains all the data the user sees in the browser.  For this I use [phantomjs](http://phantomjs.org/).  Phantom is a headless browser doing what the browser is doing on the client side - but on the server side.  In other words, phantom knows (among other things) how to get a web page via a URL, parse it including running all the javascript code in it (as well as getting data via AJAX calls), and give you back the HTML that reflects the DOM.  If you're using MS Visual Studio Express you many want to install phantom via this [link](http://www.nuget.org/packages/phantomjs.exe/).  
But first, when an ugly URL is sent to the server, we must catch it; For this, I added to the 'App_start' folder the following file:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Diagnostics;
using System.IO;
using System.Linq;
using System.Reflection;
using System.Web;
using System.Web.Mvc;
using System.Web.Routing;

namespace eShop.App_Start
{
    public class AjaxCrawlableAttribute : ActionFilterAttribute
    {
        private const string Fragment = "_escaped_fragment_";

        public override void OnActionExecuting(ActionExecutingContext filterContext)
        {
            var request = filterContext.RequestContext.HttpContext.Request;

            if (request.QueryString[Fragment] != null)
            {

                var url = request.Url.ToString().Replace("?_escaped_fragment_=", "#");

                filterContext.Result = new RedirectToRouteResult(
                    new RouteValueDictionary { { "controller", "HtmlSnapshot" }, { "action", "returnHTML" }, { "url", url } });
            }
            return;
        }
    }
}
```

This is called from 'filterConfig.cs' also in 'App_start':

```
using System.Web.Mvc;
using eShop.App_Start;

namespace eShop
{
    public class FilterConfig
    {
        public static void RegisterGlobalFilters(GlobalFilterCollection filters)
        {
            filters.Add(new HandleErrorAttribute());
            filters.Add(new AjaxCrawlableAttribute());
        }
    }
}
```

As you can see, 'AjaxCrawlableAttribute' routes ugly URLs to a controller named 'HtmlSnapshot', and here is this controller:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Diagnostics;
using System.IO;
using System.Linq;
using System.Web;
using System.Web.Mvc;

namespace eShop.Controllers
{
    public class HtmlSnapshotController : Controller
    {
        public ActionResult returnHTML(string url)
        {
            string appRoot = Path.GetDirectoryName(AppDomain.CurrentDomain.BaseDirectory);

            var startInfo = new ProcessStartInfo
            {
                Arguments = String.Format("{0} {1}", Path.Combine(appRoot, "seo\\createSnapshot.js"), url),
                FileName = Path.Combine(appRoot, "bin\\phantomjs.exe"),
                UseShellExecute = false,
                CreateNoWindow = true,
                RedirectStandardOutput = true,
                RedirectStandardError = true,
                RedirectStandardInput = true,
                StandardOutputEncoding = System.Text.Encoding.UTF8
            };
            var p = new Process();
            p.StartInfo = startInfo;
            p.Start();
            string output = p.StandardOutput.ReadToEnd();
            p.WaitForExit();
            ViewData["result"] = output;
            return View();
        }

    }
}
```

The associated `view` is very simple, just one line of code:
`@Html.Raw( ViewBag.result )` 
As you can see in the controller, phantom loads a javascript file named `createSnapshot.js` under a folder I created called `seo`.  Here is this javascript file:

```
var page = require('webpage').create();
var system = require('system');

var lastReceived = new Date().getTime();
var requestCount = 0;
var responseCount = 0;
var requestIds = [];
var startTime = new Date().getTime();

page.onResourceReceived = function (response) {
    if (requestIds.indexOf(response.id) !== -1) {
        lastReceived = new Date().getTime();
        responseCount++;
        requestIds[requestIds.indexOf(response.id)] = null;
    }
};
page.onResourceRequested = function (request) {
    if (requestIds.indexOf(request.id) === -1) {
        requestIds.push(request.id);
        requestCount++;
    }
};

function checkLoaded() {
    return page.evaluate(function () {
        return document.all["compositionComplete"];
    }) != null;
}
// Open the page
page.open(system.args[1], function () { });

var checkComplete = function () {
    // We don't allow it to take longer than 5 seconds but
    // don't return until all requests are finished
    if ((new Date().getTime() - lastReceived > 300 && requestCount === responseCount) || new Date().getTime() - startTime > 10000 || checkLoaded()) {
        clearInterval(checkCompleteInterval);
        var result = page.content;
        //result = result.substring(0, 10000);
        console.log(result);
        //console.log(results);
        phantom.exit();
    }
}
// Let us check to see if the page is finished rendering
var checkCompleteInterval = setInterval(checkComplete, 300);
```

I first want to thank [Thomas Davis](http://backbonetutorials.com/seo-for-single-page-apps/) for the page where I got the basic code from :-). 
You will notice something odd here: phantom keeps re-loading the page until the `checkLoaded()` function returns true.  Why is that?  this is because my specific SPA makes several AJAX call to get all the data and place it in the DOM on my page, and phantom cannot know when all the calls have completed before returning me back the HTML reflection of the DOM.  What I did here is after the final AJAX call I add a `<span id='compositionComplete'></span>`, so that if this tag exists I know the DOM is completed.  I do this in response to Durandal's `compositionComplete` event, see [here](http://durandaljs.com/documentation/Hooking-Lifecycle-Callbacks/) for more.  If this does not happen withing 10 seconds I give up (it should take only a second to so the most).  The HTML returned contains all the links that the user sees in the browser.  The script will not work properly because the `<script>` tags that do exist in the HTML snapshot do not reference the right URL.  This can be changed too in the javascript phantom file, but I don't think this is necassary because the HTML snapshort is only used by google to get the `a` links and not to run javascript; these links *do* reference a pretty URL, and if fact, if you try to see the HTML snapshot in a browser, you will get javascript errors but all the links will work properly and direct you to the server once again with a pretty URL this time getting the fully working page.
This is it.  Now the server know how to handle both pretty and ugly URLs, with push-state enabled on both server and client.  All ugly URLs are treated the same way using phantom so there's no need to create a separate controller for each type of call.
One thing you might prefer to change is not to make a general 'category/subCategory/product' call but to add a 'store' so that the link will look something like: `http://www.xyz.com/store/category/subCategory/product111`.  This will avoid the problem in my solution that all invalid URLs are treated as if they are actually calls to the 'index' controller, and I suppose that these can be handled then within the 'store' controller without the addition to the `web.config` I showed above.

Comment: I have a quick question, I think ive got this working now but when I submit my site to google, and give links to google, site maps, etc do I need to give google http://mysite.com/#! or just http://mysite.com and google will add in the _escaped_fragment_ because I have it in the meta tag?

Comment: ccorrin - to the best of my knowledge you don't need to give google anything; google's bot will find your site and look in it for pretty URLs (don't forget in the home page to add the meta tag too, as it may not contain any URLs).  the ugly URL containing the escaped_fragment is always added only by google - you should never put it yourself inside your HTMLs.  and thanks for the support :-)

Comment: thanks Bjorn & Sandra :-)  I'm working on a better version of this document, which will also include info on how to cache pages so as to make the process faster and do it in the more common use where the url does contain the controller's name; I'll post it as soon as it's ready

Comment: This is a great explanation!!. I implemented it and works like a charm in my localhost devbox. The problem is when deploying to Azure Websites because the site freezes and after a time i get a 502 error. Have you got any idea about how to deploy phantomjs to Azure??... Thanks (https://testypv.azurewebsites.net/?_escaped_fragment_=home/about)

Comment: I have no experience with Azure websites, but what comes to my mind is that perhaps the checking process for the page to fully load up is never fulfilled so the server keeps trying to reload the page again and again with no success.  perhaps that's where the problem is (even though there's a time limit to these checks so it may not be there)? try to put 'return true;' as the first line in 'checkLoaded()' and see if it makes a difference.

Comment: Let's supposed we lived in a world where every browser supported pushState. In such a world, would you even need anything more than the method to handle the "simple" urls? IOW, couldn't you take Google out of being part of the solution?

Comment: Good work, though, I would find another solution than abusing the Error page - a trick from the classic asp days.  One of many things to consider is the error logs, and all that traffic getting logged in the error log.

Comment: This is a very good explanation. I made three necessary changes though: 
1) I invoked string output = p.StandardOutput.ReadToEnd(); after            p.WaitForExit(); to avoid reading the output before the process finishes.

Comment: 2) I invoked string output = p.StandardOutput.ReadToEnd(); after         p.WaitForExit(); to avoid reading the output before the process finishes.

3) I added handling of errors to be informed of such in case they occur on the production server.
if (process.ExitCode != 0)
{
  Log.Error("Snapshot Error:" + process.StandardError.ReadToEnd();)
}

Comment: A correction of my last comments: Invoking p.StandardOutput.ReadToEnd(); after p.WaitForExit(); was wrong. You did it right. Sorry.

Comment: isn't is better to use href in <a> tags instead of onclick, we just need some javascript code to parse the href and link it to some function... this way google can parse <a> tags too.

Comment: code works in localhost. but after deploying in godaddy it shows "An error occurred while processing your request.". why it is happening..?? i m using angularjs and asp.net

Comment: "Provide clean URLs without fragment identifiers (# or #!)" https://webmasters.googleblog.com/2016/11/building-indexable-progressive-web-apps.html

Answer (score 33):

Google is now able to render SPA pages:
[Deprecating our AJAX crawling scheme](https://googlewebmastercentral.blogspot.ca/2015/10/deprecating-our-ajax-crawling-scheme.html)

Comment: Googlebot can execute JavaScript and render SPA pages, however there are still a number of things you need to do to make your site crawlable and SEO friendly.  1. Assign URLs to content 2. Use `<a href=...>` links in the DOM rather than relying on click events for all navigation.  3. Ensure that the correct pages renders when visiting a URL.

Answer (score 4):

Here is a link to a screencast-recording from my Ember.js Training class I hosted in London on August 14th. It outlines a strategy for both your client-side application and for you server-side application, as well as gives a live demonstration of how implementing these features will provide your JavaScript Single-Page-App with graceful degradation even for users with JavaScript turned off.

It uses PhantomJS to aid in crawling your website.

In short, the steps required are:

- Have a hosted version of the web application you want to crawl, this site needs to have ALL of the data you have in production
- Write a JavaScript application (PhantomJS Script) to load your website
- Add index.html ( or “/“ ) to the list of URLs to crawl

  - Pop the first URL added to the crawl-list
  - Load page and render its DOM
  - Find any links on the loaded page that links to your own site (URL filtering)
  - Add this link to a list of “crawlable” URLS, if its not already crawled
  - Store the rendered DOM to a file on the file system, but strip away ALL script-tags first
  - At the end, create a Sitemap.xml file with the crawled URLs

Once this step is done, its up to your backend to serve the static-version of your HTML as part of the noscript-tag on that page. This will allow Google and other search engines to crawl every single page on your website, even though your app originally is a single-page-app.

Link to the screencast with the full details:

http://www.devcasts.io/p/spas-phantomjs-and-seo/#

Answer (score 2):

I used `Rendertron` to solve the SEO problem in `ASP.net core` and Angular on the client side, it is a middleware that differentiates requests based on being crawler or client, so when the request is from the crawler side the response generated with briefly and quickly on the fly.

- rendered site for normal clients: [image: image1]
- rendered site for Crawlers: [image: image2]

In `Startup.cs`

Configure rendertron services:

```
public void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services)
{
    // Add rendertron services
    services.AddRendertron(options =>
    {
        // rendertron service url
        options.RendertronUrl = "http://rendertron:3000/render/";

        // proxy url for application
        options.AppProxyUrl = "http://webapplication";

        // prerender for firefox
        //options.UserAgents.Add("firefox");

        // inject shady dom
        options.InjectShadyDom = true;
        
        // use http compression
        options.AcceptCompression = true;
    });
}
```

It is true that this method is a little different and requires a short code to produce content specific to the crawler, but it is useful for small projects such as CMS or portal site, etc.

This method can be done in most programming languages ​​or server-side frameworks such as `ASP.net core`, `Python (Django)`, `Express.js`, `Firebase`.

To view the source and more details: https://github.com/GoogleChrome/rendertron

Answer (score 2):

##### Year 2021 Update

- SPA should use [History API](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/History_API) in order to be SEO friendly.

  > Transitions between SPA pages are typically effected via `history.pushState(path)` call. What happens next is framework dependent. In case React is used, a component called React Router monitors `history` and displays/renders the React component configured for the `path` used.
- Achieving SEO for a simple SPA is [straightforward](https://codelabs.developers.google.com/codelabs/making-a-single-page-app-search-friendly).
- Achieving SEO for a more advanced SPA (that uses selective prerendering for better performance) is more involved as shown in the [article](https://hackernoon.com/single-page-application-dispelling-seo-myths). I'm the author.

Answer (score 0):

You can use or create your own service for prerender your SPA with the service called prerender. You can check it out on his website [prerender.io](https://prerender.io) and on his [github project](https://github.com/prerender/prerender) (It uses PhantomJS and it renderize your website for you).

It's very easy to start with. You only have to redirect crawlers requests to the service and they will receive the rendered html.

Comment: While this link may answer the question, it is better to include the essential parts of the answer here and provide the link for reference.  Link-only answers can become invalid if the linked page changes. - [From Review](/review/low-quality-posts/10807544)

Comment: You are right. I have updated my comment... I hope now it be more precise.