# How to make the AngularJs content Visible in Viewsource

Tags: javascript, angularjs, view, client-side, view-source

I have taken the **lot of contents using AngularJs**.

But the **contents are not showing in the view source**.

**View page should show the contents in view source using AngularJs**.

Let me know, If there is any method to use to **show the contents in view source** of view page using **AngularJs**.

Now My Contents using AngularJs is **not visible** in the view source of my website.

Comment: That's normal, DOM is constructed on the fly by angularjs... the only way to view the source is by using the dev tools like chrome debug / firebug etc ... Why do you want to see the source ? SEO concerns ?

Comment: @Cétia:For SEO, Is there any other way to get the contents on?

Comment: @KesaVan Hi did u get any solution for this...??? please guide me also... now am facing same issue..

Answer (score 1):

This is expected JavaScript behaviour. Changes done after the page has loaded into the browser are not visible in the "view source"

Answer (score 1):

That's normal, DOM is constructed on the fly by angularjs... the only way to view the source is by using the dev tools like chrome debug / firebug etc

If you have some SEO concernrs, you'll need a way to let google parse your content. So you'll need to build your pages server sides and not clientside.

For that you can for example use see https://prerender.io/ for example, that will preprocess your angular pages serverside

See also [How to make a SPA SEO crawlable?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18530258/how-to-make-a-spa-seo-crawlable)

EDIT: Google seems to also execute javascript  : http://ng-learn.org/2014/05/SEO-Google-crawl-JavaScript/ & http://googlewebmastercentral.blogspot.fr/2014/05/understanding-web-pages-better.html