# AngularJs contents not visible in View source

Tags: javascript, json, angularjs, view, web-crawler

I have a site which was coded by AngularJs, It has SEO problem.

Noe I used [**ANGULARJS SEO**](http://lawsonry.com/2014/05/diy-angularjs-seo-with-phantomjs-the-easy-way/)  using **PhantomJS**.

I followed these full steps, But at the last it runs successfully upto this command

```
$ phantomjs --disk-cache=no angular-seo-server.js [port] [URL prefix]
```

But Now also my **angularjs code only visible** in view source.

I **cant get the contents** in view source.

Also i want to know the **Equivalent word of CURL in ASP.NET**

Any help is Appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

Configuring for serving pre-rendered `HTML from Javascript` pages/apps using the Prerender Service will resolve your issue..

As you are using PhantomJS integrated with AngularJS for your app, we can have the following reference,

https://github.com/prerender/prerender

`.htaccess` also helps the DOM to pre-render HTML from Javascript, which has been referenced in the following link..

[How to make a SPA SEO crawlable?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18530258/how-to-make-a-spa-seo-crawlable)

https://gist.github.com/Stanback/7028309

https://gist.github.com/thoop/8072354

Hope this gives you more info as I resolved above..