# How to make ajax content indexed by google?

Tags: javascript, ajax, angularjs, seo, client-side

I am in initial stages of creating a public website with client-side rendering using AngularJS. I've read in many forms that dynamic generated content won't be indexed by Google. Is there any way to go forward without affecting search engine indexing and ranking or should I shift to the conventional development ?

My client want it to be done in AngularJS. So I just wanna make sure that there is no workaround before I start convincing them.

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it is about SEO

Comment: SEO is added as a tag. So it is not offtopic @JohnConde

Comment: Click on the tag and read it :)

Comment: http://www.yearofmoo.com/2012/11/angularjs-and-seo.html and Related: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18530258/how-to-make-a-spa-seo-crawlable

Comment: Asking how search engines will display/rank/parse your site is off topic

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[Googlebot can now process JavaScript](http://googlewebmastercentral.blogspot.com/2014/05/understanding-web-pages-better.html) so you don't need to do anything to make that content accessible to Google

Answer (score 0):

You can also use a service like prerender.io or built your own pre-rendered version by using tools like PhantomJS.

Here is a nice article about AngularJS SEO with PhantomJS:
http://lawsonry.com/2014/05/diy-angularjs-seo-with-phantomjs-the-easy-way/