# does jhipster projects appears in search engines

Tags: seo, search-engine, single-page-application, jhipster

as I know Jhipster is a single page web application, does search engines like google able to index its public pages?

Answer (score 1):

you are correct: the monolithic app or the gateway of a microservice jhipster insance is a spa, i.e. all the technics that are applied to spa pages to be crawled by google should be posible to be added also to a jhipster applilcation. An intresting post is [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18530258/how-to-make-a-spa-seo-crawlable)

Comment: Thanks 'duderoot' for your reply, I will check the post and keep you updated with my trial, I am newbie in jhipster and it is my first SPA so it might take time.

Comment: updates : - [this solution](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18530258/how-to-make-a-spa-seo-crawlable) was based on [old google recommendation](https://developers.google.com/webmasters/ajax-crawling/docs/learn-more?hl=iw&csw=1), recently google announced that they are [Depreciating it](https://webmasters.googleblog.com/2015/10/deprecating-our-ajax-crawling-scheme.html) and just I have to make sure that js and css accessible for the crawler, now added a stiemap.xml and will wait  for couple of days to check if google will index it or not ... will keep u updated with results.

Comment: Yes I recently did a client engagement on the SEO of a JHipster application, it works very well

Comment: updates:- after adding a sitemap.xml & submitting it to google webmaster I wait for one day and today the sitemap is processed with zero "-" indexed pages :(

Comment: @JulienDubois thanks for your reply, and want to thank you first for providing Jhipster ...   maybe I did not understand "client engagement" in your reply, is there a readymade solution in Jhipster to have SEO done, or I should follow [this post](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18530258/how-to-make-a-spa-seo-crawlable) ?