# Is there any way to create indexable application with Marionette & Laravel?

Tags: javascript, php, laravel, backbone.js, marionette

I'am study to create web applications with Marionette, on server side using Laravel. Application gets data from server in JSON format, then Marionette build a layout and filling views with data. All ok, but this application type is not indexable by search engines (for example, Google).

Is there any way to create indexable application with Marionette & Laravel?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18530258/how-to-make-a-spa-seo-crawlable

Comment: @EricGuan Thank you for answear, but I think decision must be more easier. For example, as I know in nodejs we can render static indexable & dynamic pages using one code base. I'am searching such way with Laravel & Marionette.